# Issue in implementing RabbitMQ client in MONO

Tags: mono, rabbitmq

I have encountered a problem in implementing a very simple RabbitMQ client in C# under MONO. I'm using the following environment:
OS : Ubuntu 16.04
MonoDevelop : 5.10
.net Assembly : RabbitMQ.Client.dll version 3.6.5.0

I have a RabbitMQ server running on my pc. If I run the command

```
sudo rabbitmqctl status
```

I obtain the following result

```
Status of node 'rabbit@federico-pc' ...
[{pid,9948},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.6.5"},
      {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.6.5"},
      {webmachine,"webmachine","1.10.3"},
      {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.13.1"},
      {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","7.3"},
      {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","1.1.1"},
      {crypto,"CRYPTO","3.6.3"},
      {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.6.5"},
      {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 4.0.2","4.0.2"},
      {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","6.0.3"},
      {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.5"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","6.2"},
      {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","1.7"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.5"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.13.3"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4"},
      {rabbit_common,[],"3.6.5"},
      {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.2.1"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.10"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.7"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.8"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","4.2"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{total,55360120},
      {connection_readers,0},
      {connection_writers,0},
      {connection_channels,0},
      {connection_other,2712},
      {queue_procs,2712},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,389184},
      {other_proc,18455960},
      {mnesia,68360},
      {mgmt_db,424248},
      {msg_index,51504},
      {other_ets,1445848},
      {binary,98976},
      {code,27797472},
      {atom,1000601},
      {other_system,5622543}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,1549926400},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,231269703680},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,924},{total_used,2},{sockets_limit,829},{sockets_used,0}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,229}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,5890},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]
```

This is the C# code of the very simple client

```
using System;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
namespace provaRabbit
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory ();
            factory.HostName = "localhost";
            factory.UserName = "test";
            factory.Password = "test";
            factory.VirtualHost = ConnectionFactory.DefaultVHost;
            factory.Port     = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;

            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection ())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel ()) 
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare (queue: "hello",
                    durable: false,
                    exclusive: false,
                    autoDelete: false,
                    arguments: null);

                string message = "Hello World!";
                var body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (message);

                channel.BasicPublish (exchange: "",
                    routingKey: "hello",
                    basicProperties: null,
                    body: body);
                Console.WriteLine (" [x] Sent {0}", message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine (" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine ();


        }
    }
}
```

Of course I have created a "test" user with relevant password and I gave him administrator privileges.
When I try to debug the program I obtain the following exception

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method 'IPAddress.MapToIPv6' not found.
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x0004d] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Linq.Buffer`1[TElement]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00087] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00011] in <filename unknown>:0
  at RabbitMQ.Client.TcpClientAdapter.BeginConnect (System.String host, Int32 port, System.AsyncCallback requestCallback, System.Object state) [0x00044] in <filename unknown>:0
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.Connect (ITcpClient socket, RabbitMQ.Client.AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Int32 timeout) [0x0000f] in <filename unknown>:0
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor (RabbitMQ.Client.AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, System.Func`2 socketFactory, Int32 connectionTimeout, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout) [0x0003f] in <filename unknown>:0
  at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.ProtocolBase.CreateFrameHandler (RabbitMQ.Client.AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, System.Func`2 socketFactory, Int32 connectionTimeout, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler (RabbitMQ.Client.AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint) [0x00005] in <filename unknown>:0
  at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection (IList`1 endpoints, System.String clientProvidedName) [0x0007e] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection (IList`1 endpoints, System.String clientProvidedName) [0x0009b] in <filename unknown>:0
  at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection (IList`1 hostnames, System.String clientProvidedName) [0x0001d] in <filename unknown>:0
  at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection () [0x00013] in <filename unknown>:0
  at provaRabbit.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00029] in /home/federico/Scrivania/rabbitMQ/provaRabbit/provaRabbit/Program.cs:16
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Regards

Federico

Answer (score 0):

that error usually means RabbitMQ is not running, or is on a server that can't be reached at all.

try a couple of things to see if it is running, other than "status".

run `sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues`

and/or go to http://localhost:15672

if both of those work, rabbitmq is definitely running. at which point, i would wonder if you have a firewall or security setting preventing you from connecting to your own localhost on port 5672 (the RabbitMQ port).

you may also want to add a "connection timeout" to the connection configuration. Set it to something high, like 2 minutes.

(see https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.1.1/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.1.1-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.html - and the `connectionFactory.RequestedConnectionTimeout` setting)

It's possible your machine is just taking a while to make the connection and the C# code thinks it is not available because of that.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. I'm sure RabbitMQ server is running, since I can access to the web manager, on port 15672, and the system responds to shell commands. I have tried to change the connectionFactory.RequestedConnectionTimeout property to 120000 but I have obtained the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem.
The trick is using the built in libraries: System.Messaging, Mono.Messaging, Mono.Messaging.RabbitMQ, RabbitMQ.Client.

A very simple working code is

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Messaging;
using Mono.Messaging;
using Mono.Messaging.RabbitMQ;
using RabbitMQ.Client;

namespace provaRabbitMQ
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string message = "";
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory ();
            factory.HostName = "localhost";
            factory.Port = 5672;
            factory.UserName = "guest";
            factory.Password = "guest";
            factory.RequestedHeartbeat = 60;

            IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection ();
            IModel channel = connection.CreateModel ();

            channel.QueueDeclare ("try", true);
            message = "Hello World!";
            byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                routingKey: "try",
                basicProperties: null,
                body: body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);


        Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Federico